# CSS ISSUE: google Chrome not displaying the back groung Image and hence Drop down list not getting displayed properly

Tags: asp.net, css

I have an application developed which has to be used across all browsers especially in Chrome. I have dropdown list which is using the following CSS as shown

```
.ddlStyle{
    background-image: url("../Images/navigation_bg.jpg");
    background-color:Gray;
    background-color:Gray;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height:25px;
    width:auto;
    width:100px;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS;
    border:1px;
    border:ThreeDShadow;
}
```

The background image is not getting loaded properly in Chrome , In safari , IE and Mozilla its working Fine.

Can you help?

Comment: What's happening to the image?

Comment: Worth noting, you have two references of background colour.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .ddlStyle{
        background-image: url("../Images/navigation_bg.jpg");
        background-color:Gray;
        background-color:Gray;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        height:25px;
        width:auto;
        width:100px;
        font-family:Trebuchet MS;
        border:1px;
        border:ThreeDShadow;

        -webkit-appearance: none;

      }
```

try `-webkit-appearance: none;`

Comment: Its Working With this, Chrome is Displaying the Image, But then the Arrow Tool of Drop Down list is also getting that style which is making it invisible   .......  The Drop Down Arrow is not it self visible but when Clicked Showing the List .. Since i know that its  a Drop Down, i Can use it but then someone who does not know will not click on it since Arrow is nt visible